# No manual pdf created during build of R package

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, roxygen2

I see that my recent package build no longer creates a manual even though I have not added "--no-manual" to the build settings. I didn't have this problem before - I have recently updated both devtools and roxygen2.

Am I missing something?

Here is how I set my project options:

[image]

Comment: Try in plain R console to ensure that problem is related to RStudio/roxygen/devtools and not to R.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution would just be to run `$ R CMD Rd2pdf <package name>` if the package is already built, or uncheck `Use devtools package functions if available`

[image: devtools box]

For whatever reason, devtools injects `--as-cran --no-manual` into the build process, even though you don't specify it as a user (you can see this in your build log in RStudio).

Comment: Thank you for this information! The unchecking trick does indeed work. I have notified Hadley of the issue.